# jQuery no reconoce los inputs clonados

Tags: jquery

JQuery no me reconoce los objetos clonados, tengo un código Jquery el cual clona un div y cambia el nombre a los inputs que tiene dentro, la cosa es que necesito realizar ciertas funciones con esos inputs clonados y estoy comprobando que jQuery no los reconoce, como si no existieran, os dejo por aquí el código, gracias de antemano.

**Código Jquery clonacion y cambio de nombre de ID (El código trabaja perfecto)**

```
    $('#div-materiales-{{$num}}').clone().appendTo('#material-form').prop('id', 'div-materiales-' + i);

    $('#div-materiales-' + i).find('input.total').attr('id', "total-" + i);
    $('#div-materiales-' + i).find('input.total').attr('name', "total-" + i);
```

**Código que deberia mostrar un alert al cliquear el input total-1**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#total-1").click(function() {


        alert('funciona');

    });



});
```

PD: Entiendo que es la clonacioón que me da problemas por que el total inicial es total-0 y el código de arriba pero con total-0 me salta el alert pero como he comentado aqui el **total-1 (que seria el clonado)** no consigo que me salte el alert.

Answer (score 0):

Para que jQuery pueda "reconocer" el input nuevo debes agregarle el evento luego de agregar el nuevo input al DOM y no antes, veo que lo estas haciendo en el document.ready, y debes hacerlo luego de tener el elemento en el DOM, por lo que te sugiero hacer lo siguiente:

```
$('#div-materiales-{{$num}}').clone().appendTo('#material-form').prop('id', 'div-materiales-' + i);
$('#div-materiales-' + i).find('input.total').attr('id', "total-" + i);
$('#div-materiales-' + i).find('input.total').attr('name', "total-" + i);
$("#total-"+i).click(function() {
    alert('funciona total-'+i);
});
```

Espero te sea de ayuda.

Comment: No amigo de esa manera lo intente ya y no funciona

Comment: Agrega de forma manual el evento .click al input una vez lo crees, `$("#total-1")....`